# What is props.children?

Tags: reactjs

I am following this tutorial and the instructor did something like this to explain Higher order component

```
const aux = (props) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

and then **imported** this to some other file and replaced `div` tag with, for say `<Aux>` tag.

Now, It's sort of hard for me to understand this because I am not really sure what **`props.children`** actually do (since we hardly used it previously throughout our lectures).

I did some googling and went through an article or two on web but for some reason, their description was vey vague.

Can someone explain me the use of **`props.children`** in general?

Comment: https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891

Comment: `props.children` refers to any child elements passed into the component.

Comment: @RoyJ that was the first article which popped up and definitely an interesting one but I got lost in this statement **When invoking the <Picture> component I am passing a <Button> component as it’s children and this is then rendered due to using {props.children} in the definition of the <Picture> component.**

Comment: The official docs seem to cover that: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**props.children** is a prop like every other prop in React, but it's passed differently (when using JSX) between tags:

```
<Component>text</Component>
```

What you put between the tags will be passed to component as `props.children`. It [can be](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-node):

> undefined, null, a boolean, a number, a string, a
>   React element, or an array of any of those types recursively.

It can also be a function that returns one of the above ^ to create [render prop pattern.](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#___gatsby)

If you want to directly work on `children` prop (`filter` or `map` them), you will probably need some [React utility functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren).

That's pretty much it. There are of course more details in [React documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx)

Comment: I believe that it is also important to note that the example given in question is actually a way of replacing the <div/> tag when you need to return a list of children components, but you do not really want to put them under a <div/> - as explained by @steve-bohmbach, there may be styling issues.

Comment: is props.children used at all in vanilla JS? or it is solely react code?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou only in React

Answer (score 1):

Usually, each component's children is actually an array. but when there is only a single child, props.children will be the single child component having no array wrapper.

So in this case : `const aux = (props) => props.children;`
this will return a component.

Answer (score 1):

The  standard has been built in to react 16.3 and replaced as just <>. You would use this when you need to render multiple components but do not wish to wrap them i a  due to styling or any other number of reasons.

for example :

```
     <CustomeHeader />
     <CustomTable />
     <CustomFooter />
```

can not be rendered in react but :

```
     <>
       <CustomeHeader />
       <CustomTable />
       <CustomFooter />
     </>
```

or:

```
   <aux>
      <CustomeHeader />
      <CustomTable />
      <CustomFooter />
   </aux>
```

both above will work. whats inside the Aux or <>

Answer (score 0):

props.children is usually used while creating container components where container components will have different types of child components at different instances.

```
class Container extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="Header">AppName</div>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The container component can be used like,

```
<Container>
  <div>foo</div>
</Container>
```